# IIS multiple URL Rewrite rules

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I have IIS installed on one server and need to have few url **rewrite** rules. All of the rules have to point to different servers/urls. For example:

```
http://my-iis-server       --> http://web-server-0/category
http://my-iis-server/site1 --> http://web-server-1/category1
http://my-iis-server/site2 --> http://web-server-2/category20
http://my-iis-server/site3 --> http://web-server-3/category33
```

The first rule was easy. The problems began when trying to implement the rest of the rules (`/site1, /site2, /site3`)

If i have the following pattern: `Pattern: site1(.*) Rewrite URL: http://web-server-1/{R:1}` and navigate to: `http://my-iis-server/site1` the result is **404** and the url is changed to: `http://my-iis-server/category1` which dont exists ofc.

Any idea how to keep the `siteX` in the main url?

Is this correct approach in general? Is it going to be cleaner/easier with virtual directories?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewirte rule:

```
            <rule name="for site 1">
                <match url="site1(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://web-server-1/category1{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="for site 2">
              <match url="site2(.*)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="http://web-server-2/category20{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="for site 3">
              <match url="site3(.*)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="http://web-server-3/category33{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="for site 4">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="http://web-server-0/category" />
            </rule>
```